# Find an XML child by an attribute

Tags: collada, pugixml

I'm using `PugiXML 1.5` and trying to find a specific child in a giant XML, having a specific attribute. Specifically, this XML is a *Collada DAE* file.

I know how to find an immediate child ie. by an attribute by doing this:

```
collada.child("library_visual_scenes").child("visual_scene").
child("node").find_child_by_attribute("instance_geometry", "url", "#myurl");
```

The problem is that a `library_visual_scenes` can perfectly have something like this:

```
<library_visual_scenes>
   <visual_scene>
      <node>
      ...
         <node>
         ..
            <node>
               <instance_geometry url="this_is_what_i_want">
               ...
```

So, instead of writing the obvious *parsing all nodes inside nodes*, is there another flavor of `find_child_by_attribute` that searches into nested nodes for retrieving a child with a specific attribute?

**UPDATE**

I tried @zeuxcg Xpath suggestion and still didn't fetch me the node. The HTML fragment is the following. I'm not really used to *XPath* (used to CSS queries mostly)

```
...
<library_visual_scenes>
  <visual_scene id="xyzscene">
    <node name="EnvironmentAmbientLight">
      <instance_light url="#EnvironmentAmbientLight"/>
    </node>
    <node id="node-foo" name="foo">
      <instance_geometry url="#foo-url">
...
```

I tried the following Xpath url and didn't worked:

```
/library_visual_scenes/visual_scene//node/instance_geometry[@url='#foo-url']
```

But this worked:

```
//library_visual_scenes/visual_scene//node/instance_geometry[@url='#foo-url']
```

I learnt that `//` means *search all nodes* but `library_visual_scenes` is a single node in existence. Any explanation why i needed the `//`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
doc.select_node("/library_geometries//geometry[@id='value']")
```

Note that this results in looking for this node in the entire subtree; for COLLADA it's frequently more efficient to build a map from string to node once and then use it for all lookups. IIRC ids have to be globally unique so you can just build the map for the entire tree once using code like this:

```
unordered_map<string, xml_node> map;

for (xpath_node item: doc.select_nodes("//@id"))
    map[item.attribute().value()] = item.parent();
```

Comment: thanx for the suggestion, didn't knew the PugiXML handles XPath as well :) (although, never used to it). While i solved the issue, can you check my question update for an explanation? BTW, kudos for your excellent library :)

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot that COLLADA documents have a root COLLADA tag. This is why you need //. Or use /COLLADA/...